# What to do so the C implementation of sha1_block_data_order is taken in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

In OpenSSL there is a asm and a C implementation of `sha1_block_data_order`. I do

```
$ openssl dgst -sha1 data.txt.
```

Then the asm implementation is taken. What do I have to do so the C implementation is taken?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 1):

This is selected at compilation time of OpenSSL.

If you don't want to use the assembly language implementations, you should pass option `no-asm` to `./config` or `./Configure` as described in the `INSTALL`, `INSTALL.W32` or other `INSTALL*`, depending on your platform:

```
   no-asm        Do not use assembler code.
```

For instance on Linux/UNIX systems:

```
$ ./config no-asm [other options] --prefix=/some/dir
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

On Windows:

```
> perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm --prefix=c:/some/openssl/dir
> ms\do_ms
> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak test
> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install
```